# How to use Calendar.getInstance with specified Locale

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to use `Calendar.getInstance(Locale l)` with specified `Locale` and is not working. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

The Java Doc. say:

> **getInstance
>   public static Calendar getInstance(Locale aLocale)**
>   Gets a calendar using the default time zone and specified locale. **The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the given locale.**
>   Parameters:
>   aLocale - the locale for the week data
>   Returns:
>   a Calendar.

My code:

```
 public static void main (String[] args){

     Locale local = new Locale("pt", "BR");

     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(local); // here I am using the method
     System.out.println(c.getTime()); // and here, I cannot figure out why is not working


     DateFormat dt = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, local);
     String s = dt.format(c.getTime());
     System.out.println(s); // here just a example in portuguese Brasil
 }
```

Output:

> Wed Apr 29 10:18:16 BRT 2015
>
> 29 de Abril de 2015

Should the first `print` must be in `Locale("pt", "BR")`, in portuguese?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Answer by Loc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945430/642706) is correct: Your call to [`Calendar::getTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) produces a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object. The `java.util.Date` class has no explicit time zone yet its `toString` method confusingly applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating a String.

All very confusing names and behavior - some of the *many* reasons to avoid these poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Instead you should be using the java.time classes that officially supplant the old classes.

## java.time

Get the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

You can create a String to represent that value with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatting by calling `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-09-28T19:38:21Z

The code in the Question ignores the issue of time zone. When you do not specify a time zone your JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. Better to specify explicitly.

Note that **`Locale` and time zone are two completely separate distinct issues**.

- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.
- Time zone determines the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) used to present the date-time value.

You can have any combination of the two. For example, a time zone of Kolkata India with a French locale, or a Brazil Portuguese locale with an Auckland New Zealand time zone.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
```

Apply the time zone as a `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime`. Conceptually, think of it as `ZonedDateTime = ( Instant + ZoneID )`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

The `Locale` does not affect the meaning, on the presentation. We can let the `Locale` object drive the automatic localization of when producing a String to represent the date-time value via the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Specify a [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                       .withLocale( locale );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

Dump to console. The `instant` and `zdt` objects seen here represent the very same moment, the same point on the timeline. The only difference is a view through the lens of a different region’s wall-clock time.

```
System.out.println ( "instant.toString(): " + instant 
                     + " | zdt: " + zdt 
                     + " | output: " + output );
```

> instant.toString(): 2016-09-28T20:20:38.242Z | zdt: 2016-09-29T09:20:38.242+13:00[Pacific/Auckland] | output: Quinta-feira, 29 de Setembro de 2016 09h20min38s NZDT

## Conversion

Avoid the old `.Date` and `.Calendar` classes. But if you must use them with old code not yet updated for the java.time types, you can convert. Use new methods added to the old classes. Here we call [`java.util.GregorianCalendar.from( ZonedDateTime )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from-java.time.ZonedDateTime-).

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

And, going the other direction:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Your first print is just print Date information & Java using Default locale for this print (English)

```
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

This print will perform:  c.getTime().toString() method, and this method using Default locale (ENGLISH) - You can take a look at Date.toString() source code to see Java using Default locale.

That is why the output is 'Wed Apr 29 10:18:16 BRT 2015'

If you want print output is in portuguese. You must go with Second print.

Comment: I'm not sure if you follow the question... What you are saying is obvious. The question is what I'm doing wrong, since I used the getInstance(Locale l) and the documentation say another thing.

Comment: Calendar.getInstance(local) is just return Calendar instance, but when Java perform c.getTime().toString() ---> Java does not use portuguese locale to perform toString()

Comment: if the `c.getTime().toString()` don't use the Calendar with the `Locale("pt","BR")`, which methods use this `Locale` , and what the purpose of the `getInstance(Locale)` if the `getTime` dont use it?

Comment: You must distinguish this:  Date data in Calendar/Date instance ( long timestamp) with the Date output. They are different because the date data in Calendar/Date is just Long timestamp and from this Long timestamp, you can output to whatever format in whatever locale

Comment: yes, but I cannot understand, so what the meaning of `getInstance()` with `Locale` ? What is the purpose? which method I can use, with the `Locale` acting on the `Calendar`

Comment: There are a lot of reason such as:  TimeZone, What first day of the week. Each Locale may have different first day of the week ( Sat, Sun, Or Mon)