# Calculating seconds left till midnight of a specific time zone

Tags: android, date, time, calendar

I am trying to write a code that calculates how many time in seconds left till midnight in a specific timezone.

The time zone I am targeting is EDT which is "GMT-04:00".

I found many topics cover time calculation but none of them helped me figure out the trick to calculate seconds left to midnight in a specific time zone.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the logic you’re looking for? (Don’t look at the question, just the first answer, referring to Calendar, Locales and TimeZones)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757060/1552960

Using Calendar and time zones to calculate the exact time, then simply use that calendar object to find the difference between another set calendar object at midnight :)

long differenceInMillis = midnightCalendarObject.getTimeInMillis() - calendarObject.getTimeInMillis();

long secondsUntilMidnight = TimeUnit.toSeconds(differenceInMillis);

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
    ZonedDateTime midnight = now.toLocalDate().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(zone);
    long secondsLeftTillMidnight = Duration.between(now, midnight).getSeconds();
    System.out.println("Seconds till midnight: " + secondsLeftTillMidnight
            + ". Time now: " + now + '.');
```

Output just now:

> Seconds till midnight: 34801. Time now: 2018-10-01T14:19:58.651572-04:00[America/New_York].

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).